# Convert between QLayout and QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlayout

I have two examples where I'm basically creating wrapper objects rather than what would ideally be a simple conversion.

If `foo` is a `QWidget*` instantiated earlier, can I avoid creating a wrapper `QLayout` for it:

```
const auto layout = new QVBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget( foo );
const auto frame = new QLabel( QLatin1String( "Why Do I Need a Layout?" ) );
frame->setLayout( layout );
```

If `foo` is a `QLayout*` instantiated earlier, can I avoid creating a wrapper `QWidget` for it:

```
const auto widget = new QWidget();
widget->setLayout( foo );
const auto tabs = new QTabWidget();
tabs->addTab( widget, QLatin1String( "Why Do I Need a Widget?" ) );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, or what you want do achieve. Could you maybe add some details?

Comment: `layout` is a wrapper, I don't need the `QLayout`, it doesn't do anything, but I can't call `frame->setWidget( foo );` cause `QLabel` doesn't have that function. I'm asking if there's a way I can skip the `layout` wrapper. Same thing for the `widget` wrapper.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to add a child to a Widget without adding a Layout, and you want to add a Layout as child where a QWidget is expected?

Comment: @MatthiasB yup exactly. I find myself creating a lot of these wrapper objects in my code, and I just wanted to know if there was a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Widget doesn't have to have a layout. You can add child widgets by just setting it as their parent, but then you will have to adjust the size and position of the child widgets manually.

Comment: @thuga "Widget doesn't have to have a layout." You're saying that with regard to the first case? you're suggesting that doing `foo->setParent( frame )` would remove my need for `layout` while achieving the same behavior?

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, it's regarding the first case. I'm not saying it will achieve the same behavior. Like I said you will have to adjust the child widget's size and position manually.

Comment: @thuga After a fair amount of research I believe that your `setParent()` solution is the closest out there to what I'm asking for. If you'd be willing to put that in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widget doesn't have to have a layout. You can add child widgets to a widget by setting the widget as their parent. But then you will have to adjust the size and position of the child widgets manually.

Comment: This was the best answer for my situation, but it was a pretty unique situation. For the general populace the solution @BeniBela gave may be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Just can always write your own wrapper functions:

```
QLayout* wrap(QWidget* w){
    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget( w );
    return layout;
}
QWidget* wrap(QLayout* l){
    auto widget = new QWidget();
    widget->setLayout( l );
    return widget;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I suppose this is reasonable if there is no more direct way to convert.